# angular 2 material matTooltip multiline

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to Angular 2 Material. What's the preferred way to make a tool tip multi-line?

For example, I might have the following tool tip:

```
AA BBBBBBBBBB CCCC DDDDD
```

And, I may want to to have it display in a multi-line format like this:

```
AA BBBBBBBBBB 
CCCC 
DDDDD
```

Comment: Either `<br>` or `<li>` or `\n` or `&#13`.

Comment: @Jonas Since it's against the Material specs for what you're trying to do and the Angular Material team follows the guidelines as closely as possible, there's no **official** solution for this.

Comment: @Edric I couldn't find the Material specs (in 2020) that says line break on tooltips is a no no.

Answer (score 101):

First, create a class for your tooltip, to make it break lines on line breaks.

```
.my-tooltip {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Then, add the class to your tooltip and insert line breaks with the Unicode code `&#13;`

```
<span 
    matTooltip="First line&#13;Second line"
    matTooltipClass="my-tooltip">
</span>
```

Comment: why not `matTooltipClass="my-tooltip"` instead of `[matTooltipClass]="'my-tooltip'"` ?

Comment: Do you have any idea why it works like this `[matTooltip]="'I am goin&#13;crazy here'"` but not if I have a public variable `text = "I am goin&#13;crazy here";` and set it like this: `[matTooltip]="text"? The first example makes new lines, the second just prints out the `&#13;`..

Comment: I would recommend you to open a new question in SO explaining the details.

Comment: @displayname , I think the CSS style runs before angular evaluates the variable. I simply use \n on the text in my variable and it worked

Comment: I didn't know this CSS option, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me using the [matTooltip] attribute in angular 14 :-(

Comment: I needed to add the css to a global file. In the css of the component it did not work.

Comment: I used the below line on scss file using angular 6 and it worked.
Thanks

::ng-deep .mat-tooltip  {
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}

Answer (score 37):

You can achieve the same thing without even the need of `\n` or `<br>`.
Just write your content as it is, if you need it to be multi-lined. For example:

```
"abc
 abc
 abc"
```

All you have to do is to add this to your global css:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip  {
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2021**

The above solution is pretty old and `::ng-deep` is deprecated as pointed out by @bsplosion in the comments.

If you don't want to use the solution of @rodris you can alternatively just edit the class directly. Add this to your global stylesheet:

```css
.mat-tooltip  {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying to leverage `::ng-deep` for this (or, really, for most things).  First, [it's deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), and second, it's a bad habit that'll make CSS bug hunts a real pain.  In this case, the style should work just fine without `::ng-deep` and `!important` if you just put it in the global stylesheet for your project (whichever one is in your angular.json>architect>build>options>styles setting).

Comment: Yeah, even back in late 2017 this wasn't recommended practice - check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43586539/2738164) for an example of using global styles instead of `::ng-deep`.  Even before that, you could always just apply a linked stylesheet in the index.html which would propagate through all components.

Comment: Couldn't find a reference to ng-deep from your link @bsplosion

Comment: @KieranRyan I just tried the link and it still goes straight to the deprecation notes about it for me.  As a note, [Chrome also has published guidelines on how they're handling shadow-piercing descendants now](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6750456638341120) (September 2022).

Answer (score 23):

In My Example I am using angular 6, Material Design. My Issue was 'I have array of string' and I have to show it in multiline MatTooltip. I handle the situation and it works for me. Here is code

```css
.mat-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p matTooltip="{{myArray.join('\n')}}" >...</p>
```

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me (Angular 12). I put the .mat-tooltip style in the global stylesheet.

Answer (score 19):

none of this worked for me in my project i.e using angular 7,8  I found the solution from
here [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrrwqb?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.css)

In html

```
<img src="assets/icons/about.png"  width="15px" height="15px" matTooltip="{{getMoreInformation()}}"  matTooltipClass="test"/>
```

In ts file

```
 getMoreInformation(): string {
    return 'Address : Home \n  Tel : Number';// \n represent break line here
    }
```

in your style.css file(remember project style.css)

```
.test {
    white-space: pre-line;
  }
```

Hope it help someone. ps keep coding

Comment: Thanks! With your example I found that \n works when calling a function while &#13; works when the toolTip text is in html

Comment: This fixed my exact issue, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

You can simply do:

**HTML**:

```
<button matTooltip="AA BBBBBBBBBB 
   CCCC 
   DDDDD">
   Hello world !
</button>
```

**CSS**:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line; // Allow line break
}
```

**Result**:

[image: Tooltip]

Comment: is ::ng-deep depricated? as mentioned in the above answeres?

Comment: @Abdul Most of users use `ng-deep`, while it's written as deprecated the Angular team will maintain it for sure as users need it. The example I wrote is for a component. You can avoid the use of `ng-deep` by using a global style (`styles.css`) or `ViewEncapsulation.NONE`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Angular 14 and neither of the answers worked for me right away.
First I added a class to the `mat-tooltip`:

```
<mat-icon
  [matTooltip]="tooltip"
  matTooltipClass="tooltip-class"
</mat-icon>
```

I also needed to add ::ng-deep to the css (sass in my case):

```
::ng-deep .tooltip-class
  white-space: pre-line
```

The Unicode line break `&#13;` also didn't work. Since I'm using string template a line break in the `.ts` file worked:

```
const tootltipText = `${strings.method}: ${strings.note}
                      ${strings.reason}: ${strings.snapshot}`
```

I also tested adding `\n` and it works both with regular strings and string tamplates:

```
const tootltipText = 'line\nbreak\nworks'
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer Angular Material versions 16+
To adapt the Material 3 design, they have changed the classes from `mat-tooltip` to `mdc-tooltip`.

```scss
::ng-deep .mdc-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer to this problem

I am using angular 14.

Please don't use "**mat-tooltip**" class, as it doesn't work, choose another name for your class like "tooltip-multiline".

```
<h6 [matTooltip]="'Mango\nApple\nOrange'" matTooltipClass="tooltip-multiline" >
```

show more

```
::ng-deep .tooltip-multiline {
white-space: pre-line;
```

}

You can also use a variable "tooltip" present in .ts file,

```
tooltip = 'Mango\nApple\nOrange'
<h6 [matTooltip]="tooltip" matTooltipClass="tooltip-multiline" >
```

[image]