# Angular Tooltip does not recognize '\r' or '\n' characters

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So to outline the use case: 
From my back-end service i receive a list of objects which I break apart using ngFor and display using . I attach a toolTip to this card to show a info about the item. The info for each item is a list of elements. For the tooltip I send the list to a function and join the items of the list with '\r\n' characters however the tooltip doesn't read the characters at all and just shows a contiguous string in the tooltip

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemList; ">
 <mat-card matTooltip="{{getDesc(item)}}">
    <span class="card-title" style="font-size: 12px">
      {{ item.itemName }}
    </span>
 </mat-card>
</div>
```

The toolTip description function:

```
getDesc(item){
  let itemDesc: any;
  if(item.itemDescList !== null)
    itemDesc = item.itemDescList.join('\r\n')
  return itemDesc
}
```

how can I introduce those newlines in the tooltip?

example array: [ 'desc 1 : some text', 'desc 2: some text', ...] these need to be shown on new lines in the tooltip

Comment: Do you not need to use <br/>

Comment: sorry how? do I introduce it like I would the new line?

Comment: using .join('<br/'>) introduces it as a literal character in the tooltip string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 material matTooltip multiline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058483/angular-2-material-mattooltip-multiline)

Comment: I saw that before but it's adding a newline at whitespaces. My array of desc strings have spaces in them. So I need the newline to be by array index not at a white space

Comment: Similar issue with solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058483/angular-2-material-mattooltip-multiline/61389854#61389854)

Answer (score 7):

This has been answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058483/angular-2-material-mattooltip-multiline).

First, create a class that will add the `white-space: pre-line` style. Put it inside your styles.scss file, or other root level css file; if you want to place it in a component's stylesheet, prefix the class with ::ng-deep:

```css
// in root stylesheet
.line-broken-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
// in component's stylesheet
::ng-deep .line-broken-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Then add the class by using the `matTooltipClass` input.

To test it out, you can add a new-line delimiter, `&#13;`, between the sections you want broken-up:

```html
<mat-card    
    matTooltip="One line&#13;Two line"
    matTooltipClass="line-broken-tooltip">
</mat-card>
```

or

```js
this.tooltipText = 'One line&#13;Two line';
```

```html
<mat-card    
    [matTooltip]="tooltipText"
    matTooltipClass="line-broken-tooltip">
</mat-card>
```

And to test it without explicitly stating the delimiter, use a template string instead, so that the new-line is preserved:

```js
this.tooltipText = `
  This value has been updated.
  Confidence: ${this.confidence}
`;
```

```html
<p    
   [matTooltip]="tooltipText"
    matTooltipClass="line-broken-tooltip">
A02.0 - Salmonella enteritis 
</p>
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me (I've tried to do the same here: https://stackblitz.com/angular/keqjqmxbrbg?file=app%2Ftooltip-position-example.html)

Comment: @Edwin , you'll need to fork the stackblitz example and save your changes. The link you posted takes me to a project that doesn't have the solution I've mentioned, so I am unable to help you out.

Comment: In an Angular 9 project, I had to prefix the stylesheet entry with `::ng-deep` to make it work.

Comment: It didn't work for me as well :(

Comment: Артур Гудиев, do you have a stackblitz example? Or, some code to look at?

Answer (score 4):

**Angular 8/9**

For `Angular 8/9` below solution (using `::ng-deep`) worked for me,

```
::ng-deep {
 .mat-tooltip-class-here {
  white-space: pre-line;
 }
}
```

```
<span    
    matTooltip="First line \n Second line"
    matTooltipClass="mat-tooltip-class-here">
</span>
```

Comment: Working in Angular 12

Comment: Does not work in angular 16

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following CSS

```
.mat-tooltip {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```css
.with-pre-line
{
 white-space: pre-line;
 }
```

```html
<div>
without white-space: pre-line; 
some text with spaces
and 
newlines
<div>




<div class="with-pre-line">
with white-space: pre-line;
some text with spaces
and 
newlines only breaks
on newlines
<div>
```

Comment: Doesn't this work only with whitespace? my array will look something like this
[ 'desc 1: this', 'desc 2: that'] so adding new line at the white space won't work. Desc 1 and desc 2 need to be on their ownlines

Comment: I've added an example pre-line only breaks at line breaks not all whitespace, unless it needs to, to stop the text being longer than the container.

Comment: adding to my card. it adds spaces between the cards and thier element but the tooltip is unaffected...

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the newline character but rather with the tooltip itself. I tried introducing whitespace: pre-line but it didn't affect the tooltip at all

Comment: I used ::ng-deep and that was able to solve my problem I know its deprecated but that was the only solution that worked. As outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058483/angular-2-material-mattooltip-multiline

Answer (score -1):

Use `<br />`.

To insert HTML into a tag with Angular, use: `<span class="card-title" style="font-size: 12px" [innerHTML]="item.itemName"></span>`

Comment: How can I apply innerHTML to the matTooltip

Comment: to be clear the tooltip is generated as [matTooltip]='someString' how can I introduce [innerHTML] here?

Comment: You can't add innerHTML to mat tooltip