# Angular Material matTooltip break line elements

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Im using Angular 7 and Angular material matTooltip.

I want that the tooltip displays every element in the next line, something like this:

[image]

But, instead I'm getting this:

[image]

I got 3 elements per line, and I don't want that. I want one element/line.

My code is as follows:

**app.component.ts**

```js
items=['15-09-2020: 200','16-09-2020: 200','17-09-2020: 200', '18-09-2020: 200'];
newItems = this.items.join("\r\n");
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="col col-sm-2" matTooltipPosition="after" matTooltip="{{ items}}"></div>
```

Check this example that is not working for me:

[Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrrwqb-mydve2?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular 2 material matTooltip multiline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058483/angular-2-material-mattooltip-multiline)

Comment: I tried that, not working

Answer (score 0):

Source : https://www.angularjswiki.com/material/tooltip/

It's a bit late, to people who want to have breaklines in the tooltip,
you create a custom class in your global CSS and add this class with "matTooltipClass".

**HTML**

```
<button mat-raised-button
    matTooltip="Multiline Tooltip &#13; This is second line"
    matTooltipClass="multiline-tooltip">
    Multiline tooltip
</button>
```

**Global CSS**

```
.multiline-tooltip{
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

---

You can also add in your specific component, you should add

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

to your *component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tooltip',
  templateUrl: './tooltip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tooltip.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

https://siderite.dev/blog/styling-angular-material-tooltips.html/

Hope this can help others

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Asaf is working perfectly for me.
Angular 14

```
matTooltip="Component: Test &#13;&#10;Last updated date: 2023-01-17T09:17:02.753Z"
```

[Mattooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I9ms.png)

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed this in my project using `&#13;&#10;`

So, what you'll need to do is:

```
newItems = this.items.join("&#13;&#10;");
```

Another thing, you need to change this:

```
matTooltip="{{ items}}"
```

To this:

```
[matTooltip]="items"
```

Comment: Not working, its prints me this: 15:09:2020&#13;&#10;: 25... literally