# Why is the New line character \n not working in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to add a new line in the matToolTip attribute in Angular app , but its not reflecting in the output .

```
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> <div style="min-width: 100px;">{{row.Status}}  </div> 
  <div *ngIf="row.Date!=null" style="margin-left: 70px;"><mat-icon [matTooltip]="'Date/Time: ' + row.Date + '\n' + '\nVersion: ' + row.Version" >info</mat-icon>
   </div> 
   </mat-cell>
```

Can anyone help on why \n is not producing a new line in the tooltip section ?

TIA

Comment: `\n` isn't a thing in HTML. If you want a new line you need to use something like `<br/>` or some CSS

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47350957/3334365