# Show object inside Angular Material Tooltip

Tags: json, angular, angular-material, tooltip

I have an object with several key-value pairs which I want to show in a tooltip when hovering over an icon.
If I use JSON.stringify to pass the object to a string, the format shown inside the tooltip is really ugly, without any breaking line or space even if I include the space argument of the stringify.

How can I do to show prettier raw JSON data inside a tooltip?

**component.ts**

```
[...]
ngOnInit(): {
    this.myToolTip = JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 4)
}
```

**component.html**

```
[...]
<mat-icon [matTooltip]="myToolTip">whatever_icon</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material Tooltip does not support this out of the box. You have to modify it like here: [angular 2 material matTooltip multiline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058483/angular-2-material-mattooltip-multiline)

**style.css**

```
.mat-tooltip  {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```