# How can I add my own CSS file in Angular?

Tags: angular

Like `styles.css`, I want to add my own CSS (like `my_custom.css`, not Bootstrap) globally in my Angular project.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Global CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273463/angular-2-global-css-file)

Comment: why not just put your styles in that file? why cant you do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add you style file(i.e custom.css) at project root level(same level as styles.css)
and then you can register it in angular-cli.json 
i.e

```
"apps":[
  {
    "styles":["style.css","custom.css"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can import CSS files in your global style `style.css` file.

```
@import 'custom.css';
```